# Should a new access control mechanism use a precedence-based or an order-based permission system?

Tags: design, permissions, rules-and-constraints

Let's say I have users, groups (or "roles") and resources, and I want to manage various permissions on those resources. As far as I can see, there are two main "philosophies" when it comes to permissions.

---

For lack of a better word, I'll call the first one "**precedence-based**", and it's used, for example, by [NTFS](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-precedence.htm) or [SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131153/5273):

```
* All Resources: DENY Group G1
* All Resources: ALLOW Group G2
* Resource R1:   ALLOW Group G1
* Resource R1:   ALLOW User U
```

You have a (configurable) **unordered** set of permissions, and a (built-in) ordered list of precendence rules (e.g. "user permissions override group permissions", "DENY permissions override ALLOW permissions", etc.) which determine which rule applies.

---

The other system, which I will call "**order-based**", is used, for example, by [iptables](https://askubuntu.com/q/423630/284094):

```
1. Resource R1:   ALLOW User U
2. All Resources: DENY Group G1
3. Resource R1:   ALLOW Group G1
4. All Resources: ALLOW Group G2
(5. DENY)
```

We have a (configurable) **ordered** list of rules (with an implicit final DENY or ALLOW rule). They are processed sequentially and the first matching rule applies.

---

I am tempted to choose the second system, because it seems (a) much simpler to understand (no complex precedence rules) and (b) more powerful (just a gut feeling).

However, the first system is widely used as well, so it surely must have some advantages. What are they?

Comment: @Downvoter: Feedback to improve my question is appreciated.

Comment: both systems are widely used, but they are different, what are the requirements of your application

Comment: @Ewan: The requirements of my application are: It must be possible to grant or deny users and/or groups access to specific parts of the application. For example: "User A may not access form F" or "Only Group B may access report R". Anyway, I'm also interested in general thoughts on that matter. Thus, if you can think of any special case where the first system is better suited than the second, please mention it.

Comment: this would normally be done with role based permissions, where you don't  specify any denied rules and therefore the order is unimportant

Comment: @Ewan: But what if a customer needs more complex rules (e.g. "Group A may not access form F unless the user is also in group B")? The software will (hopefully) be sold many times and I cannot know how complex the customer's security requirements will be. I want a future-proof solution, but I also don't want to burden my software with unneeded complexity. That's why I ask for the drawbacks and advantages of both systems, so that I can make an informed decision based on the cost/benefit trade-off.

Comment: well, you need to work out the actual requirements then. tbh though role based security is pretty ubiquitous these days. If its just user access you are controlling I dont think you'll go far wrong with it

Comment: *"tbh though role based security is pretty ubiquitous these days."* Both systems presented in my question are role-based, so that doesn't really help in choosing between them. :-) *"well, you need to work out the actual requirements then."* No, because if it turns out that system X is strictly better than system Y, I can just use system X, and I'll be better off, even if the requirements change. That's why I want to understand the advantages and weaknesses of both systems.

Comment: no they are permissions based

Comment: @Ewan: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: the two schemes you have outlined are permission based not role based

Comment: @Ewan: Why? (I thought that "role" was just a synonym for "group".)

Comment: it is. but in both your example you have lists of permissions. if you are doing user access this is not a good thing

Comment: @Ewan: Why? What alternative do you suggest?